# Golang how can I access a slices fields from html/template

Tags: go

I have a `[]struct{}` and that `[]struct{}` has a field called `ThreadName` and I'm trying to access that from in the template like so:

`{{ index .Posts 0 $.ThreadName}}`

not sure how to do this properly any information would be great thanks.

Comment: Provide more code to understand the issue and also what is the current outcome of the thing you tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following to access the thread name of the first post:

```
{{(index .Posts 0).ThreadName}}
```

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/wUxh7rwp-w)

Comment: what if  the field i want to access is an variable? `(index .Posts 0).$fieldName ` doesn't work